# How to fix cropped shadow in a AnimatedList?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I use AnimatedList but a use shadow in item, my item like code below, I need some help!!!

```
class TextSentMessage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String textMessage;
  final Widget buildStatus;

  TextSentMessage({this.textMessage, this.buildStatus});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('message 4 : ' + textMessage);
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
      children: <Widget>[
        Stack(
          overflow: Overflow.visible,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 10.0, bottom: 10.0, left: 20.0, right: 15.0),
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                constraints: BoxConstraints(
                    maxWidth: 0.7 * MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    minWidth: 50.0),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 117, 255),
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                        color: black_7, blurRadius: 64, offset: Offset(0, 7))
                  ],
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                      topRight: Radius.circular(20),
                      bottomRight: Radius.circular(6),
                      bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20)),
                ),
                child: Text(textMessage,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'UTM Avo',
                        fontSize: 15.0,
                        color: Colors.white))),
          ],
        ),
        buildStatus
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

This is I use ListView.builder : https://i.stack.imgur.com/PII8W.jpg

This is I use AnimatedList : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y623Y.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not able to replicate your issue @quyen.

This is the test I did on iOS simulator & flutter 1.5.4-hotfix.2 (stable channel):

**Animated List:**
     child: AnimatedList(
              initialItemCount: msgs.length,
              itemBuilder:
                  (BuildContext ctx, int index, Animation animation) {
                return TextSentMessage(
                  buildStatus: Icon(
                    Icons.check_circle,
                    size: 18,
                    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 117, 255),
                  ),
                  textMessage: msgs[index],
                );
              },
            ),

ANIMATED demo image:
[image: animated list]

**List View builder:**

```
child: ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
            return TextSentMessage(
              buildStatus: Icon(
                Icons.check_circle,
                size: 18,
                color: Colors.green,
              ),
              textMessage: 'This is a text message!',
            );
          },
          itemCount: 6,
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        ),
```

LIST VIEW demo image:
[image: list view]

Comment: Thanks! I found my issue, I warp a SizeTransition to use animation when add item, that is cropper my shadow, You can try to warp it and review for me @roipeker